# Node app created by enclose module getting shuts down on idle in production mode

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, node-modules, kinect-v2, enclose

I am working with a `node.js` application whose `.exe` has been made using `Enclose` module, although it is working fine, only problem is that the application automatically shuts down after 10 minutes opening if left idle, no interaction with it.

- Is it because of "Process working time" and "Network connections" are
  Limited in the free version?
- Will the app run continuously without shutting down if i subscribe to
  the full version?
- Will this issue be permanently fixed for the exe builds created with
  the paid version, or will the exe work fine only till my subscription
  ends?

What should I do to resolve this. OR if I have to choose any other module to launch node application for production then which module should I choose?

Can anyone who has used `Enclose` module of node js resolves this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: to be honest, if Your app makes money, it's not a problem to pay 100$ per year. but I agree that if You've done some great job why You should pay? so You've 3 ways: 1) rewrite using some nodejs framework (example: `electron`), 2) create desktop app with web view component and communicate with nodejs app that runs in bg (by executing `node app.js`), 3) create some little executable that will run nodejs app and open browser. You can keep app up and running using `pm2`, `forever` but it makes more headaches than just paying some amount and demanding for perfect service from enclosejs creators (:

Comment: have You checked this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/nexe or this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-compile

Comment: Yes i have checked nexe. it makes a bulky build and getting issues with native modules. so I rejected that.

Comment: Can I run pm2 command pragmatically, like on click of exe command of pm2 start will run ?

Comment: if You think to make `enclose`d app to keep running - You cannot. cuz app will shut down and re-run again that is not good for UX

Comment: seems like You've only one way: `pay for enclosejs` for 1 one month and if everything will go well, so pay for another month and so on...

Comment: ok thanks for your help but i will keep looking for another solution and also try if I can run the PM2 pragmatically.

Comment: sorry that I didn't gave exceptional answer. I'm don't like to make desktop apps using nodejs without proper desktop framework. wish You to find good solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132159/discussion-between-deep-kakkar-and-num8er).

Comment: I have purchased enclose js paid version, now it is working fine .

Comment: Oh that business world. Makes people waste money (: