# How to run asp.net core application using pm2 on linux server

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, pm2

[image]I have updated my asp.net core API over linux server using kestrel, I want to run the core application using pm2. Let me know if any buddy has already done this kind of task.

What I have tried is:

- I Installed the pm2 on my linux server (not globally). It installed successfully but when I'm trying to run the code using pm2, I am getting error `pm2, command not found`
- I tried to install the pm2 globally but getting write access issue in node modules some where but I can't give global write access.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: How exactly did you install? Di you try to do `sudo npm install -g pm2`?

Comment: I have used following commands
1. sudo npm install pm2 i.e. particular directory
2. sudo npm install -g pm2 -g i.e. global installation

Comment: When installing only for you, you may probably ensure that `~/node_modules/pm2/bin` is part of your `PATH` variable. Also checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/41317809/229864

Comment: papanito, please review the screenshot attached. I have tried to run command just now and getting the following error. Let me know if we can run server on particular directory instead of running globally.

Comment: run `sudo npm i -g pm2` cause in the screenshot you are running it without `sudo`. or when you installed it locally try `~/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2` or as mentioned add the bin path to your `PATH` variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pm2, command not found` means the binary is not found cause it is most probably missing in your `PATH` variable. The path differs whether you install it globally or not - see [pm2-command-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41317809/229864) how to figure out the path and how to add it to your `PATH` variable.

When not installed globally, the binaries are under `~\node_modules`. This you have to add the actual binary path e.g. `~/node_modules/pm2/bin` to the `PATH` variable or you call it directly using `~/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2`

For the installation problem mentioned above, run the installation as `sudo npm install -g pm2`

Comment: Thanks Installation successfull, Now I am using this command to run core api

pm2 start dotnet run

but getting error