# pm2 command not found on yarn

Tags: debian, yarnpkg, pm2

I try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38185590/pm2-command-not-found) but i keep the same problem.

`yarn global add pm2` -> ok

`sudo pm2 status` -> `sudo: pm2: command not found`

`pm2 status` -> `-bash: pm2: command not found`

In my `~/.bashrc` i add the following line :

```
export PATH=$PATH:usr/bin/pm2
```

because `whereis pm2` return `/usr/bin/pm2` but nothing change

I test this path too : `yarn bin` -> `/home/user/node_modules/.bin` but nothing too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution :

```
find * -name "pm2"
```

i got some line :

```
home/myUser/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/pm2
home/myUser/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/pm2/pm2
home/myUser/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2
home/myUser/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/pm2/lib/templates/logrotate.d/pm2
home/myUser/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin/pm2
home/myUser/.cache/yarn/v6/npm-pm2-4.1.2-97f852c731d307a60dde1ef2fc5a622813ab6cf4-integrity/node_modules/pm2
home/myUser/.cache/yarn/v6/npm-pm2-4.1.2-97f852c731d307a60dde1ef2fc5a622813ab6cf4-integrity/node_modules/pm2/pm2
home/myUser/.cache/yarn/v6/npm-pm2-4.1.2-97f852c731d307a60dde1ef2fc5a622813ab6cf4-integrity/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2
home/myUser/.cache/yarn/v6/npm-pm2-4.1.2-97f852c731d307a60dde1ef2fc5a622813ab6cf4-integrity/node_modules/pm2/.bin/pm2
home/myUser/.cache/yarn/v6/npm-pm2-4.1.2-97f852c731d307a60dde1ef2fc5a622813ab6cf4-integrity/node_modules/pm2/lib/templates/logrotate.d/pm2
home/myUser/.yarn/bin/pm2
```

i test each :

```
home/myUser/.yarn/bin/pm2 ls
```

one work : `home/myUser/.yarn/bin/pm2`

so i edit my bashrc with `export PATH=$PATH:home/myUser/.yarn/bin/`

and test :

```
xxxxx@xxxxx:/$ pm2 ls
┌────┬─────────────────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id │ name                    │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status   │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├────┼─────────────────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 1  │ main                    │ 0.0.1   │ fork    │ 15499    │ 44s    │ 136  │ online   │ 0.2%     │ 76.3mb   │ xxxxx    │ disabled │
│ 2  │ main                    │ 0.0.1   │ fork    │ 15470    │ 59s    │ 29   │ online   │ 0.2%     │ 77.3mb   │ xxxxx    │ disabled │
│ 0  │ node                    │ N/A     │ fork    │ 0        │ 0      │ 60   │ errored  │ 0%       │ 0b       │ xxxxx    │ disabled │
└────┴─────────────────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```